# WLTC0017E:Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called error

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I am having issue with a restful web service deployed on WebSphere 7. Each time I try to access a url I'm getting this error message:

```
"WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called".
```

I am suspecting my indirect lookups as the cause of the problem. I have my look up code like this

```
try {
    this.em = (EntityManager) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/persistence/BACPOnlineAPPPU);
    this.utx = (UserTransaction) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);

    }
```

Apart from this, I have created my datasource and tested successfully with WebSphere. What is the evil i am doing wrong?

Here is my stack trace:

```
[10/6/11 10:21:26:888 WAT] 0000001d LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[10/6/11 10:21:26:888 WAT] 0000001d webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[ServletAdaptor]: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.transaction.RollbackException
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService.commitTx(PersistenceService.java:83)
    at com.tavia.service.GltmMisCodesResource.get(GltmMisCodesResource.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:149)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:259)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:941)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:384)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:451)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:632)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.stage3CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1224)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:998)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:919)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.UserTransactionImpl.commit(UserTransactionImpl.java:293)
    at com.tavia.service.PersistenceService.commitTx(PersistenceService.java:81)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: Are there other errors in the log (e.g., transaction timeout) that might explain the rollback only?  My only suggestion is to chop bits out of the servlet request processing until you narrow down what code has called setRollbackOnly.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely seeing a transaction timeout. What you should do is to ensure that your application commits changes. Also you could increase the database timeouts of WAS. You can find them under "Transaction service".